# only second message is sent to topic

Tags: c++, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! i was writing a code where is publish a simple message to an existing topic. The problem is, that only on the second time i send a message is actually heard by the topic. Making the first message non existing.

Here's the code i used:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h"

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   ros::init(argc, argv, "trajectory_test_node");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;

   ros::Rate loop_rate(0.2);
   ros::Publisher r_arm_comand_publisher = nh.advertise<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory>
   ("/signbot/r_arm_controller/command", 1000);

   // Create a message to send.
   trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory msg;

  // Fill the names of the joints to be controlled.
  // Note that the vacuum_gripper_joint is not controllable.
   msg.joint_names.clear();
   msg.joint_names.push_back("r_shoulder_joint");
   msg.joint_names.push_back("r_top_arm_joint");
   msg.joint_names.push_back("r_elbow_joint");
   msg.joint_names.push_back("r_wrist_joint");
   // Create one point in the trajectory.
    msg.points.resize(1);
   // Resize the vector to the same length as the joint names.
   // Values are initialized to 0.
   msg.points[0].positions.resize(msg.joint_names.size(), 0.0);
    msg.points[0].time_from_start = ros::Duration(1.0);

   if(ros::ok())
  {
    r_arm_comand_publisher.publish(msg);

   ros::spinOnce();
   loop_rate.sleep();
   ROS_INFO_STREAM ("\n1 - command SENT:\n" << msg);
   // *****************************************************************
   r_arm_comand_publisher.publish(msg);

   ros::spinOnce();
   loop_rate.sleep();
   ROS_INFO_STREAM ("\n2 - command SENT:\n" << msg);
 }
 loop_rate.sleep();
 ROS_INFO_STREAM("\n\n\t***** SHUTTING DOWN ********\n\n");
 return 0;
}
```

on the terminal where i execute the program, is printed this:
[image: image description]

on the other terminal where i use rostopic echo, is printed this:
[image: image description]

Could someone help me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269223/only-second-message-is-sent-to-topic/) by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-08-21**:
Might be a duplicate of [11167](https://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message/). If so try to sleep a short moment before publishing.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-21**:
It's good practice to copy and paste (formatted) terminal output rather than posting screen shots of it. http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do

**Comment by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on 2017-08-22**:
Humpelstilzchen: no, its not a duplicate, but thanks for the link, Atually i didnt find this question when i was searching on ros answers. i will try the solutions to see if i can resolve my problem.
jayess: thanks for the advice, i correct that from now on, in my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the problem. As say in [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message/) "I guess the problem is that ROS needs some time to register at the core and to establish all subscriber connections". Which means, before publishing any message i should wait just a little time. So i use `sleep(5);` just before i call the publish() method.
I could also write:

```
while(r_arm_comand_publisher.getNumSubscribers() != 1)
{
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("\n\tWaiting for subscibers\n number of subs:"<<r_arm_comand_publisher.getNumSubscribers()<<"\n");
  sleep(5);
}
```

but i am working with simulator gazebo, and i start the gazebo first. So there is always at least one subscriber listening.

---

Originally posted by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) with karma: 137 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0